# retrieveing image from the sqlite gives error?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to store image into SQLite and then retrieve the image back. I have searched other post related to it and got some clues and leads but now i am stuck and getting error which i do not know WHY ?

The image store into the SQLite Database Successfully but when i try to get the image i get the error

> **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.**

Below is my code

**SQL Helper Class**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class SQLHelperClass  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {



    public static  int DATABASE_VERSION = 12;
    public static  String DATABASE_NAME = "user_image_save.db";

    public static  String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE";
    public static  String TEXT_TYPE = "TEXT";
    public static String BLOB = "BLOB";
    public static  String INTEGER_TYPE = "INTEGER";
    public static  String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" ;
    public static  String AUTOINCREMENT = "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" ;


    public SQLHelperClass(Context context ){
        super(context , DATABASE_NAME , null , DATABASE_VERSION);

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE + " " + SQL_Constants.SavedIntoSQL.TABLE_SQL_SAVE_IMAGE

                + " ( " + SQL_Constants.SavedIntoSQL._ID + " " + AUTOINCREMENT + " , "
                +         SQL_Constants.SavedIntoSQL.COLUMN_OWNER_ID + " " + TEXT_TYPE + " , "
                +         SQL_Constants.SavedIntoSQL.COLUMN_NAME + " " + TEXT_TYPE + " , "
                +         SQL_Constants.SavedIntoSQL.COLUMN_EMAIL + " " + TEXT_TYPE + " , "
                +         SQL_Constants.SavedIntoSQL.COLUMN_IMAGE + " " + BLOB+ ")" );

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }
}
```

**Constant Class**

```
import android.provider.BaseColumns;


import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public final class SQL_Constants {

    public static abstract class SavedIntoSQL implements BaseColumns {

        public static final String TABLE_SQL_SAVE_IMAGE = "imageSave";

        public static final String ID_DATA = _ID ;
        public static final String COLUMN_OWNER_ID = "owner_id";
        public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
        public static final String COLUMN_IMAGE = "user_image";



    }

}
```

**Storing Data into SQLite**

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                                    resource.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
                                                    byte[] bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();


                                                    Toast.makeText(UpdatedUserProfile.this, "Download Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

                                                    contentValues.put(SQL_Constants.SavedIntoSQL.COLUMN_OWNER_ID, App.getAppInstance().getCurrentUser().getProperty("ownerId").toString());
                                                    contentValues.put(SQL_Constants.SavedIntoSQL.COLUMN_NAME, App.getAppInstance().getCurrentUser().getProperty("name").toString());
                                                    contentValues.put(SQL_Constants.SavedIntoSQL.COLUMN_EMAIL, App.getAppInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail());
                                                    contentValues.put(SQL_Constants.SavedIntoSQL.COLUMN_IMAGE, bytes);


                                                    sqLiteDatabase.insert(SQL_Constants.SavedIntoSQL.TABLE_SQL_SAVE_IMAGE, null, contentValues);
```

**Getting The Data Back**

```
sqlHelperClass = new SQLHelperClass(UpdatedUserProfile.this);
        sqLiteDatabase = sqlHelperClass.getWritableDatabase();
        sqLiteDatabase = sqlHelperClass.getReadableDatabase();

        String projection [] = {

                SQL_Constants.SavedIntoSQL.COLUMN_OWNER_ID ,
                SQL_Constants.SavedIntoSQL.COLUMN_EMAIL ,
                SQL_Constants.SavedIntoSQL.COLUMN_NAME ,


        };


        cursor =  sqLiteDatabase.query(SQL_Constants.SavedIntoSQL.TABLE_SQL_SAVE_IMAGE , projection,
                null , null , null , null , null);



            cursor.moveToPosition(0);

            int statusOwnerId = cursor.getColumnIndex(SQL_Constants.SavedIntoSQL.COLUMN_OWNER_ID);
            int statusName = cursor.getColumnIndex(SQL_Constants.SavedIntoSQL.COLUMN_NAME);
            int statusEmail = cursor.getColumnIndex(SQL_Constants.SavedIntoSQL.COLUMN_EMAIL);
            int statusImage = cursor.getColumnIndex(SQL_Constants.SavedIntoSQL.COLUMN_IMAGE);

            String ownerIdAgain = cursor.getString(statusOwnerId);
            String name = cursor.getString(statusName);
            String email = cursor.getString(statusEmail);
            byte [] image = cursor.getBlob(statusImage);

            String compareValueOwnerId = sharedPreferencesDatabaseActivity.getString("userId", "");
            String compareValueUserName = sharedPreferencesDatabaseActivity.getString("userName", "");
            String compareValueEmail = sharedPreferencesDatabaseActivity.getString("userEmail", "");
```

i am getting all other data i.e name , email , owner_id but when i comes to image i get the error

This is the line that causes error

> byte [] image = cursor.getBlob(statusImage);

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `projection` does not have `COLUMN_IMAGE` so `cursor.getColumnIndex(SQL_Constants.SavedIntoSQL.COLUMN_IMAGE)` returns -1. Attempting to read column -1 causes this exception.

Adding the column to your projection helps if the image blobs are small enough. Android SQLite cursors have a limited-size window and in practice you cannot query rows larger than 2MB. If that's the case for you, consider refactoring your code so that you're not storing the images in the database. Rather store them in the file system and just store their paths in the database.

Comment: What a fool i am .. You are right .. I spend like 3 or 4 (i think) hours trying to figure out what is wrong .. Thank you for pointing out :P